# JSIL and DllImport

Tags: javascript, c#, pinvoke, jsil

I try to convert sample .net application with P/Invoke to javascript with [JSIL](http://jsil.org).

C# code:

```
[DllImport("JSTestLib", EntryPoint = "Get42", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public unsafe static extern int Get42();
```

Generated javascript:

```
$.ExternalMethod({Static:true , Public:true }, "Get42", 
  JSIL.MethodSignature.Return($.Int32)
);
```

Where should I add implementation of the Get42 method in javascript? Should I register this method manually in JSIL?

I have only an error now:

> The external method 'System.Int32 Get42()' of type 'Test.Program' has
>   not been implemented.

Comment: jsil transform to javascript only MSIL command, but when you use P/Invoke, MSIL does not contain code for external function, so JSIL transform only declaration

Comment: I know, that's only the declaration. I don't know where I have to place the implementation.

Comment: if you have implementation, why you use extern? just add implementation to you function, also you can see about [verbatim javascript](http://jsil.org/#samples/verbatim.html)

Comment: I ask, because I want translate to javascript native lib too (on C++). With Emscripten for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use JSIL.ImplementExternals - take a look at JSIL.Core.js for examples